# how many process are created?

Tags: process, fork

How many processes are created by the program? Can you explain to me step by step how I determine the total number of processes and how to consider the two "exit(0)" ?

```
int main(){
   int pid, i;
   for (i = 0; i <= 3; i + +) { 
      pid=fork();
      if (pid == 0 && i == 1) exit(0); 
   }
   exit(0);
}
```

I tried to calculate the number of processes but I don't know how to handle the instruction after pid=fork() and exit(0)